# Separate admin and user login form or no?

Tags: authentication, admin, login-page

I could not find a place to ask this question. If I did not ask my questions in the right place, I apologize and thank you for leading me to the right place.

Do you think it is better to use a login form for the security of a project or two login forms, one for administrators and the other for users?

Some people say that in order to increase the security of the site, it is better for the admin login page to be separate from the user login page. It is also better to use two firewalls for this issue.
For example, in WordPress or Drupal, the admin login page is separate from the user login page.
What is your opinion?

Comment: It's an interesting question with an interesting coversation to be had.  However, opinion-based questions are explicitly off topic on Stack Overflow.  I might recommend reddit for this kind of thing

Comment: @DanielFarrell Thank you for leading me to the right place